# RCP Align the left side of the toolbar

Tags: rcp

[image]

Why is my toolbar not left justified? The first tool in front of the blank space?
Answer？ thank you！

Comment: What RCP is this? There are many different RCP products. Show us how you are defining the tool bar.

Comment: <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="toolbar:toolbar.file?after=toolbar.file.group.new">
         <command
               commandId="com.zkbp.nmr.experiment.newexp.ui.handlers.menu.NewExperiment"
               icon="resource/icons/new experiment25.png"
               id="toolbar.file.new"
               label="%command.toolbar.new.label"
               style="push">
         </command>
      </menuContribution>

Comment: This is the first tool

Comment: What eclipse rcp version are you using? and show us your whether its application toolbar or view toolbar?

Comment: Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers
Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Build id: 20150924-1200

Comment: Update your question and put plugin file and explain briefly your problem